# Facebook comments_info FQL table returning null on my app_ID

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I'm doing this facebook comments for a friend and I can't get any info with FQL nor with graph api...
I need to make him a table of all the comments with likes and so on.
I want to use FQL but trying with Graph API to see info didn't work either.

My situation is kinda complicated...

The HTML/JS for the comments runs on my server, but people use it inside a facebook page IFRAME for another app ( I switched app ID's somewhere in the middle, I only found that out now... :| ), so the comments href point to a somewhere that has the second app id in it...

This is what important inside it's code (if it's something else, tell me and I'll post it):

/* APP ID replaced with X, URL replaced with Y */

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="X">
```

.....

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=X&amp;xfbml=1">
</script>
```

....

```
<script>

FB.init({

appId  : 'X',

status : true,

cookie : true,

xfbml  : true 

});

</script>
```

.....

```
<fb:comments href="Y" numposts="10" width="490" publish_feed="true"></fb:comments>
```

---

So , I tried retrieving info with: 
https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=Y// Returns empty data
https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids={place on my server} // same thing

I tried FQL:

```
SELECT app_id, xid, count, updated_time FROM comments_info WHERE app_id="X" //returns null
```

and

```
SELECT app_id, xid, count, updated_time FROM comments_info WHERE app_id="{APP Id of IFRAME}" // returns empty data
```

Comment: sorry if I come off as rude or demanding .... This was not my intention

Comment: What is the question? Re rude & demanding: can still [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5361933/edit) to take out the emotions ;)

Comment: why does it return null..... or how do I get any info... or what am I doing wrong...

Comment: @ingerman: And if you use the `Y` id in the first FQL query you still get nothing?

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing, hoping setting the APP ID for the comment box would give me the ability to select from comments_info and get the latest comments, but always return []

Comment: `g.fql("select xid from comments_info where app_id = '123123123123123'")`
[{'xid': None}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I find out why this happened, since the Y url is part of facebook, it doesn't belong to my app thous not allowing me to access information...

Sorry for taking so much time to post this, but I forgot I asked this...  anyway - facebook comments is no fun ....